# I can not run my project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I can not run my project in android studio.
I created a basic Android project in Eclipse.
And I exported it to 'Generate Gradle build files'.

Then I imported it into the Android studio.
In the Android studio I can see the project, but the project is sync failed. 
And I can not run.

Error message? : Could not determine the class-path for class org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.

I will attach a photograph.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why don't you create brand new "Basic Project" in Android Studio itself? Android app development with Eclipse was deprecated a long time ago. We're in 2018 why do you want to use Eclipse for creating projects? Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: I have a program I developed in Eclipse a few years ago. I want to modify this program in the Android studio. However, the above error message (Could not determine the class-path for class org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.) Appears.
So I made a simple basic project and tested it, but I can not likewise run it..

Comment: Create new project in Android Studio and copy-paste code from old project to newly created project (on by one). I think this should do the trick for you.